# trying to run a spring boot application:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, maven, maven-wrapper

trying to run the downloaded simple spring boot app from spring.io initializer using

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/exception/ExceptionHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3307)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3293)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2106)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getEnhancedMainMethod(Launcher.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:261)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.exception.ExceptionHandler
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Do you actually have a space in `spring-boot:run`?

Comment: its a typo in post. do i need to install tomcat first or sth ?

Comment: No, you don't. I'm going to retag because this looks like a weird problem. I suggest you try removing the jar files in the `.mvnw` directory and trying again.